# how to generate all spanning trees from one spanning tree

Tags: graphs, minimum-spanning-tree, spanning-trees

If I have one spanning tree from a connected and undirected graph, how can I generate all other spanning trees of this graph by modifying this spanning tree one edge at a time? All intermediates must also be spanning trees of the graph.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is greatly presented in [Knuth's book](http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~wagner/knuth/fasc4a.pdf) at 7.2.1.6 (see page 23)